# how to handle dependency to a dll dynamically?

Tags: dll, odp.net

I have a dll that hides differences of different ADO.NET providers and has lots of code like:

```
private static void AppendProviderSpecificParameterCmdStr(StringBuilder sb, DbCommand cmd, string fieldNameToUse, ComparisonOperator oprtr, string parameterName)
{
    if (cmd is System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand || cmd is Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}:{2}", fieldNameToUse, GetComparisonOperatorStr(oprtr, cmd), parameterName);
    }
    else if (cmd is SqlCommand)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}@{2}", fieldNameToUse, GetComparisonOperatorStr(oprtr, cmd), parameterName);
    }
    else if (cmd is OleDbCommand)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}?", fieldNameToUse, GetComparisonOperatorStr(oprtr, cmd));
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Wrong database command type: {0},", cmd.GetType()));
    }
}
```

where Comparison operator is my own enum.

Oracle.DataAccess is present on all machines that have oracle client and this code have been ok for my needs. However now I've faced a situation where there is only SqlClient and they have no need to have oracle at all. So my code works only if I copy Oracle.DataAccess.dll which is naturally a horrible solution. How this should be done the correct way?

Thanks -matti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call a dependency on dll a horrible solution.  Your solution supports Oracle and consequently you have an oracle dll in your solution - it is what it is.

That said, there are things you could do abstract away the command type.

One - create complete data access methods that implement an interface.  Your current solution I'd classify as more of a helper or utility method for generic data access.  You could instead declare an interface specific instead to a domain - customer for example - like ICustomerDA.  In your case you'd have 3 implementations of ICustomerDA.Insert, with the database specifics buried inside.  Your main code would only need to know about ICustomerDA.  This is probably what I would do in a larger solution as differences and features between RDBMSs go well beyond parameter declaration.

Two - If you wanted to stick with more of the helper/utility idea, you could create an interface for a wrapper for db objects, say IDBCommand.  Implementations IDBCommand would hide the underlying command object, and then have specific implementations of an .AppendProviderSpecificParameterCmdStr method which would allow you to do something like:

```
OracleDbHelper : IDbCommand...
  public void AppendProviderSpecificParameterCmdStr(...){
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}:{2}", fieldNameToUse, GetComparisonOperatorStr(oprtr, cmd), parameterName);
  }

IDBCommand cmd = DAFactory.GetCommand();
cmd.AppendProviderSpecificParameterCmdStr(...
```

The key to both of these solutions is referencing by a common interface from your main project rather than individual types.  Once you did this, you could use reflection in your factory or better yet, **something like [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) to create the actual types.**

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have to check it out later. I called it horrible because copying Oracle.DataAccess.dll to a customer with no oracle is not good in my opinion. It also may involve some legal issues?

Comment: I understand completely what you mean.  However, I also find these days that semantics or "best practices" are put ahead of code that compiles and runs without issue.  You might have a point about licensing, but I doubt it's an issue: "In most cases, Oracle does not charge any fees for distributing the Oracle client nor ODP.NET with a third-party application. However, it is best to consult the licensing agreement from which you acquired rights to the Oracle software...." http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/faq-093106.html#distribute

Comment: thanks! i forgot this answer but this is actually little bit like something i did last week (wrapping). maybe subconsciously :) my solution is something like this i put in this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988358/what-does-a-using-statement-without-variable-do-when-disposing

Answer (score 0):

> So my code works only if I copy Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Not unless you *also* have the native OCI DLLs, for example because you have already installed the Oracle Client.

To avoid forcing your users to install the full Oracle Client, you can distribute the DLLs from the Oracle **Instant** Client together with the application. If user never chooses to connect to Oracle, these DLLs are never called and just sit there quietly without causing any trouble.

For some hints on what to distribute and how to cover both 32-bit and 64-bit, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15887016/533120).

We have a home-grown abstraction layer that currently works with Oracle and MS SQL Server (and is portable to any DBMS with a decent ADO.NET provider), and this system has worked quite well so far.

Comment: no. i don't need to install the other dlls. this is tried and proven. only Oracle.DataAccess.dll works fine in a machine without any kind of oracle client.

Comment: @matti Oracle.DataAccess.dll is the old "mixed-mode" ODP.NET and it requires native DLLs. Perhaps you actually meant Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll (the new "fully-managed" ODP.NET)?

Comment: sorry for late answer. this have worked without native DLLs. only copying Oracle.DataAccess.dll. note that it's not using it on sql server environments. i can't explain this or know anything about. this managed dll is completely new for me. i have to look on this. thanks.

Comment: @matti You probably had native DLLs somewhere in path without knowing it - try searching the whole file system for `oci.dll` (and others). You may also try using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to see if native DLLs were loaded inside process (and from where). The other possibility is that Oracle connection was not actually attempted at run-time (Oracle.DataAccess.dll dynamically loads native DLLs on as-needed basis).

Comment: I don't have the computers that it's working but they do not have Oracle client installed at all. it would be weird that multiple computers would have the client without people knowing it. the program does not attempt oracle connection because it opens SqlConnection.

Comment: @matti _"the program does not attempt oracle connection because it opens SqlConnection"_ - there you go. It "works" because it didn't try to load the DLLs.

Comment: hmmm. this is getting bit weird. thought that i made quite clear from the start. guess u should read my original question again. even though it never tries to open oracle connection and only sql connection it wanted Oracle.DataAccess.dll. That was my problem and wanted help how to solve it by asking the question... and the accepted answer quite well solves the problem.

Comment: @matti I'm a bit confused. If you never use Oracle.DataAccess.dll, why don't you simply remove the reference to it from your project?