# what does a using statement without variable do when disposing?

Tags: c#, transactions, using-statement

I've always used using with variable and assignment. Now i have like this a class DbProviderConnection:

```
public class DbProviderConnection : IDisposable
{
    public DbConnection Connection { get; set; }
    public DbTransaction Transaction { get; set; }

    public DbTransaction BeginTransaction()
    {
        Transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction();
        return Transaction;
    } 

    //... and so on
}
```

Now i was thinkin to use it like this:

```
using (DbProviderConnection cnctn = _planDb.CreateOpenConnection())
{
    using (cnctn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        //...
        cnctn.Transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

My question is: Is the `DbProviderConnection.Transaction.Dispose` called?

Comment: see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/yh598w02.aspx), dispose will be called

Comment: ok. it seems my question was once again poorly formed... I would like to know what is "state" of DbProviderConnection.Transaction property...

Comment: @Grundy: links to localized MSDN pages isn't a right way to go.

Comment: @Dennis yes, you're right, did not notice it :-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From [C# Specification 8.13](https://web.archive.org/web/20140208112102/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/library/aa664736(v=vs.71).aspx) using statement defined as

```
using-statement:
   using (resource-acquisition) embedded-statement
```

Where *resource-acquisition* is

```
resource-acquisition:
    local-variable-declaration
    expression
```

In first case you have using which acquires resource via local variable declaration. In second case resource is acquired via expression. So, in second case resouce will be result of `cnctn.BeginTransaction()` call, which is `DbTransaction` from your `DbProviderConnection` class. Using statement disposes its resource after usage. So, yes, `DbProviderConnection.Transaction.Dispose()` will be called.

UPDATE: According to same article, your second using block will be translated to

```
DbTransaction resource = cnctn.BeginTransaction();
try
{
    //...
    cnctn.Transaction.Commit();
}
finally 
{
   if (resource != null) 
      ((IDisposable)resource).Dispose();
}
```

Comment: @matti welcome :) I also added link to specification which describes how `using` statement works

Comment: i read that before asking and didn't get it 100%. what made me hesitate is that I assign transaction to DbProviderConnection.Transaction in BeginTransaction. If it was just method returning the object I would have known that it's disposed. But it seems it makes no difference.

Comment: @matti the only difference is that *resouce* variable is inaccessible in, and invisible to embedded statement.

Answer (score 11):

From the specification:

> **8.13 The using statement**

A using statement of the form

```
using (ResourceType resource = expression) statement
```

when ResourceType is a nullable value type or a reference type other than dynamic, the expansion is

```
{
    ResourceType resource = expression;
    try {
        statement;
    }
    finally {
        if (resource != null) ((IDisposable)resource).Dispose();
    }
}
```

A using statement of the form

```
using (expression) statement
```

has the same three possible expansions...The resource variable is inaccessible in, and invisible to, the embedded statement.

Therefore the object returned from `cnctn.BeginTransaction()` will be disposed when the block exits, but is not accessible inside the associated block.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, the Dispose will be called. the `using` statement only works with disposable objects. Like this:

```
using (DbProviderConnection cnctn = _planDb.CreateOpenConnection())
{
    using (cnctn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        // ...
        cnctn.Transaction.Commit();
    } // Here BeginTransaction.Dispose() is called.
} // Here DbProviderConnection.Dispose() is called.
```

Answer (score 1):

The object that `BeginTransaction` returns, is what will be disposed.

BeginTransaction returns a [`DbTransaction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbtransaction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so that is what will be disposed

Comment: that u don't know. it can return also OracleTransaction ;)